# show zepplin gui from host

Tags: centos, redhat, vmware, apache-zeppelin

I installed centos 7 in vmware in my windows, in the new machine I INSTAlled zeppelin, I started the service, now I want to see gui of zeppelin, I typed http://198.168.250.128:8080 in chrome in windows and that didn't work. also gui pf installed spark in my centos didn't work http://198.168.250.128:4040,

I want to know if I forgot something

Comment: Where you got ip 198.168.250.128?

Could you check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103988/need-ip-for-my-virtual-machine

Comment: I succeeded to connect to my centos using WinSCP with this @. I got this address with network manager of windows